# Python asyncio: what satisfies `isinstance( (generator-based coroutune), ???) == True`?

Tags: python, async-await, generator, python-asyncio

I'm baffled to find out neither of `typing.Awaitable` nor `collections.abc.Awaitable` cover a generator-based coroutine which is one of *awaitable*s defined in

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression

As of Python 3.6, several `asyncio` APIs such as `sleep()` and `open_connection()` actually return generator-based coroutines. I usually have no problems with applying `await` keywords to the return values of them, but I'm going to handle a mixture of normal values and *awaitable*s and I'd need to figure out which ones require `await` to yield an actual value.

So here's my question, what satisfies `isinstance(c, ???) == True` for an arbitrary generator-based coroutine `c`?  I'm not insisting on using `isinstance` for this purpose, maybe `getattr()` can be a solution...

### Background

I'm working on a tiny mock utility for unit testing of async function based on https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/unit-testing-asyncio-code which internally has a `asyncio.Queue()` of mocked return values, and I want to enhance my utility so that the queue can have *awaitable* elements, each of which triggering `await` operation. My code will look like

```
async def case01(loop):
  f = AsyncMock()
  f.side_effect = loop, []
  await f()  # blocks forever on an empty queue

async def case02(loop):
  f = AsyncMock()
  f.side_effect = loop, ['foo']
  await f() # => 'foo'
  await f() # blocks forever

async def case03(loop):
  f = AsyncMock()
  f.side_effect = loop, [asyncio.sleep(1.0, 'bar', loop=loop)]
  await f() # yields 'bar' after 1.0 sec of delay
```

For usability reason, I don't want to manually wrap the return values with `create_task()`.

I'm not sure my queue will ever legitimely contain normal, non-coroutine generators; still, the ideal solution should be able to distinguish normal generators from generator-based coroutines and skip applying `await` operation to the former.

Comment: What is the `c` you're testing for here? Is it a function object, like `case01`, or the coroutine returned by calling it, or something else?

Comment: Also, you talk about distinguishing  normal generators from generator-based coroutines. Do you mean you want to distinguish 3.4-style-`asyncio` generators using `yield from` from normal generators using `yield from`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documented way to detect objects that can be passed to `await` is with [`inspect.isawaitable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isawaitable).

According to [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression), `await` requires an awaitable object, which can be:

- A *native coroutine* - a Python function defined with `async def`;
- A generator-based coroutine - a Python generator decorated with `@types.coroutine`;
- Instance of a Python class that defines `__await__`;
- Instance of an extension type that implements `tp_as_async.am_await`.

`isinstance(o, collections.abc.Awaitable)` covers all except the 2nd one. This could be reported as a bug in `Awaitable` if it wasn't [explicitly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Awaitable), pointing to `inspect.isawaitable` to check for *all* awaitable objects.

Note that you cannot distinguish generator-based coroutine objects from regular generator-iterators by checking the type. The two have the exact same type because the `coroutine` decorator doesn't wrap the given generator, it just sets a flag on its code object. The only way to check if the object is a generator-iterator produced by a generator-based coroutine is to check its code flags, which how `inspect.isawaitable` is [implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py#L221).

A related question is why `Awaitable` only checks for the existence of `__await__` and not for other mechanisms that `await` itself uses. This is unfortunate for code that tries to use `Awaitable` to check the actual awaitability of an object, but it is not without precedent. A similar discrepancy exists between iterability and the the `Iterable` ABC:

```
class Foo:
  def __getitem__(self, item):
      raise IndexError

>>> iter(Foo())
<iterator object at 0x7f2af4ad38d0>
>>> list(Foo())
[]
```

Despite instances of `Foo` being iterable, `isinstance(Foo(), collections.abc.Iterable)` returns false.

Comment: You did a good job of pointing out the official doc already had an answer to my question!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you're trying to test here, but [the `inspect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) has functions for checking most things like this:

```
>>> async def f(c):
...     await c
>>> co = f()
>>> inspect.iscoroutinefunction(f)
True
>>> inspect.iscoroutine(co)
True
>>> inspect.isawaitable(co)
True
```

The difference between the last two is that `isawaitable` is true for anything you can `await`, not just coroutines.

If you really want to test with `isinstance`:

`isinstance(f)` is just `types.FunctionType`, which isn't very useful. To check whether it's a function that returns a `coroutine`, you need to also check its flags: `f.__code__.co_flags & inspect.CO_COROUTINE` (or you could hardcode 0x80 if you don't want to use `inspect` for some reason).

`isinstance(co)` is `types.CoroutineType`, which you *could* test for, but it's still probably not a great idea.

Comment: I'm only interested in checking `co` rather than `f` in your example, so `inspect.isawaitable` is the answer. Thanks